# Using a simples "CREATE TABLE" on SQL does not seem to work, more info

Tags: oracle

```
"CREATE TABLE bilhete(
id_bilhete int,
estado_bilhete varchar2(12),
id_viagem int,
id_cliente int,
PRIMARY KEY (id_bilhete),
FOREIGN KEY (id_viagem)
FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente)
REFERENCES viagem (id_viagem), cliente (id_cliente));

DESCRIBE bilhete;"
```

Error report -
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:
*Action:

ERROR:
ORA-04043: object bilhete does not exist

Comment: Please edit the question and indent it properly ..its not understandable

Comment: Clearly you have a lot of syntax errors. Add `,` after `FOREIGN KEY`.

Comment: Can you run  Desc "bilhete" and tell me what it returns ?

Comment: Why is the entire statement (well, two statements, actually) enclosed in double-quotes?  Was this actually extracted from an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE?  If so, don't do that.  Rarely should dynamic sql be used for DDL.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is:

```
[CONSTRAINT constraint_name] FOREIGN KEY (column_names) REFERENCES table_name ( referenced_column_names)`
```

So you need a `REFERENCES` clause for each `FOREIGN KEY`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE bilhete(
  id_bilhete     int,
  estado_bilhete varchar2(12),
  id_viagem      int,
  id_cliente     int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_bilhete),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_viagem) REFERENCES viagem (id_viagem),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES cliente (id_cliente)
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4e0c02eb64c021dbca32bdb51fb29216)

Comment: No it says this 
"Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

ERROR:
ORA-04043: object bilhete does not exist"

Comment: The ORA-00942 occurs on the "DESCRIBE bilhete;" line after the CREATE TABLE line processes. Since there are syntax errors in the CREATE TABLE, it fails. If you removed the DESCRIBE line, the error would show you the CREATE TABLE failing.

Comment: @leomarrao Oracle does not allow two statements in a single command. You need to execute the `CREATE TABLE` statement in one command (fixing the syntax errors first) and then execute the `DESCRIBE` statement in a second command.